# Расчет кол-во по условию

Tags: mysql

При на писании запроса возникла следующая проблема:
В столбце "A" есть одно кол-во в одном месте "3264" оно всегда одинаковое в столбце "Б" есть общее кол-во допустим 6883 оно может быть всегда разное.
Нужно вынести в столбец "В" полное кол-во мест и в столбец "Д" оставшееся кол-во без полных мест т.е по логике должно получится что столбец "В" = 2 а столбец "Д" = 355

```
case when oba.attr_val_float != 0 
     then ((case when cd.id != 0 
        then(select units 
             from counting_diff 
             where load_id = od.load_id 
                and counted = (select max(counted) as maxdate 
                               from counting_diff 
                               where load_id = od.load_id
                       )
         )
         else od.qty end
   )/oba.attr_val_float) 
else 0 end as mono
```

это по столбцу В в оригинале, но получаются не целые числа."
т.е. получается case when A != 0 then "Б"/"A" else 0

Comment: Отлично, теперь покажите что вы сделали и что у вас не получилось - подготовьте [mcve] и разместите его в вопросе (кнопка "править")

Comment: , case when oba.attr_val_float != 0 then ((case when cd.id != 0 then(select units from counting_diff where load_id = od.load_id and counted = (select max(counted) as maxdate from counting_diff where load_id = od.load_id)) else od.qty end)/oba.attr_val_float) else 0 end as mono - это по столбцу В в оригинале, но получаются не целые числа.

Comment: Построить Правильную логику не могу

Comment: т.е. получается case when A != 0 then "Б"/"A" else 0

Comment: **.. и разместите его в вопросе (кнопка "править")**

Comment: Решил проблему следующим способом стобец "В" обрезал не целые числа (round), столбец (Д) вычел из одного другое"

Comment: вот и славно,а то тут все равно никто не понял, в чем проблема была :D

Comment: Проблема была в длинном написании запроса: